# Unexpected camera calibration results with OpenCV over JPEG images and EXIF orientation

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, exif, camera-calibration

I am exploiting OpenCV to calibrate a set of images. I am using the standard function `cv::calibrateCamera` offered by OpenCV, nothing special here. The images are in JPEG format, and the EXIF Orientation flag is set (and it can be != 1).

I have noticed that if the images are not all top-left oriented (Orientation == 1) the calibration result is wrong, usually resulting in a very high RMS error. On the contrary, if I manually correct the orientation (using `mogrify` or `exiftool`, for instance), the result is as expected.

Have you ever encountered this kind of behavior? Can you please explain me why this is happening?

As a side note, I am using OpenCV 3.1 on a Mac OSX El Capitan, installed via Homebrew. Code is in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using imread or cvLoadImage? imread for opencv 3.1 seems to handle exif correctly, but cvLoadImage not. See the following opencv bug https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6673

Comment: Actually, I am using `imread`. Nevertheless, I do still not get the reason why image orientation should influence calibration.

Comment: Are all your images the same orientation? As a check save a copy of each image after you have found the checkerboard corners on it and written the corners onto the image. Save the image as png so you discard rotation information, and this might show you some problems

Comment: They have not the same orientation, for sure. How should that influence the calibration? I am just passing a set of point coordinates to the calibration routine, not the images themselves. Nevertheless, as I think I won't get an answer to my question, I am going to select your answer as the best (and only) one. Thanks for your time.